# Multer upload showing file as undefined in express 4

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, multer, body-parser

I'm using React/redux to post some form values to an express server. 
I'm also using Multer for file upload. Everything is working except the Multer file upload.
I'm posting my setup below in hopes someone else has had this issue. I have seen lots of posts with similar issues but nothing that seems to fix the solution for me so not trying to duplicate the issue just trying to solve the issue.

JSX form

```
<form onSubmit={this.save} ref='form' role="save" encType="multipart/form-data">
    <div className="laptop">
      <input type='file' alt="project-image" name="photo" />
    </div>
    <div className="edit-title edit-field-wrapper">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="title" />
    </div>
    <div className="edit-description edit-field-wrapper">
       <textarea type="text" className="form-control" name="description" />
    </div>
</form>
```

// Save helper function to gather form input values to be posted back to express

```
save( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    let elements = [... findDOMNode(this.refs.form).elements];
    let formData = {}, el, val;

    Object.keys(elements).map((key) => {
        el = elements[key];
        if(el.nodeName && el.nodeName!=='BUTTON'){
                val = (el.name == 'skills') ? el.value.split(',') : el.value;
                if(val.includes("fakepath")) val = val.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "");
                formData[el.name] = val;
        }
    });

    console.log("formData = ", formData);
    this.props.update( formData );
}
```

My action creator

```
export function editProject( project ){
  const headerConfig = {headers: { authorization: getLocalToken()}};
  return ( dispatch ) => {
    const dbPost = axios.post(`${config.env.ROOT_URL}/api/file`, project, 
    headerConfig);
    return dbPost.then(result => {
      dispatch({
                type: type.EDIT_PROJECT,
                payload: result.data
            });
    }).catch( error => {
      return error.response.data;
    });
  }
}
```

Route file in express

```
   const upload = multer({ dest: './public'});

app.post('/api/file', upload.single('photo'), (req, res) => {
    console.log("BODY = ", req.body); //form fields
    console.log("FILE = ", req.file); //form files
  });
```

I'm using  app.use(bodyParser.json()); so I can get my header authorization with a jwt token in it to show in req.body for other routes. 
Body comes back with all my posted formData but req.file comes back undefined every-time. This is driving me crazy for the past 10 hours. I've tried removing boadParser but still nothing. I have read body-parsey doesn't support multipart forms. but I thought Multer doesn't need body parser so why is this still coming back with file undefined.

I'm using the following

```
"express": "^4.14.1" 
"body-parser": "^1.17.1" 
"multer": "^1.3.0"
```

Comment: Anyone out there with this issue ?

Comment: late to the party... but i am experiencing similar problem. When I send a multipart request with Postman, server with `body-parser` and `multer` recognizes the file but not when I am having my async action creator function generates `fetch` call with `FormData`